# npm version issue~postversion: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s)

Tags: npm, npm-version

I am trying to use npm version to update `package.json` script and push the required changes to the github repository. I have followed below link for the same

[https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version](http://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version)

I gave `"postversion": "git push"` command in the `package.json` file. While using command - `npm version patch -m "Upgrade to %s for reasons"` I am getting below

> npm warn :postversion: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error shows up when I am running NPM as root user. The following config changes fixed the problem for me:

```
npm config set user root
npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

It would probably be better NOT to run NPM with "unsafe permissions." See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo) for ideas about how to run NPM with lower privileges.